# Incorrect favicon displayed

Tags: favicon, google-plus-one

Using Google +1 share bar in the following article http://www.thecourier.co.uk/news/coming-up-in-tuesday-s-courier-1.67323 is displaying the incorrect favicon.

I have set the favicon url as http://www.thecourier.co.uk/media/courier/resource/images/favicon.ico
but it is showing some other image.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your favicon does not include a 16x16 version.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the image at http://www.thecourier.co.uk/media/courier/resource/images/favicon.ico does not exist.